# Time taken for file_get_contents

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am using `file_exists()` and then `file_get_contents()` functions in PHP to check the existance of a remote image file and then to fetch it. Then I will `echo()` the image as the Ajax response.

Its working fine sometimes but not at some time even if the image exist. So my question is will `file_get_contents()` takes some time to get content? If so how can I make the `echo()` to wait until the file is fetched.

Thnx

Comment: Sure network transfer takes time. Why you even wonder? And BTW: I think you should use cURL for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$retrieve = false;
$file = 'my_file.php';
$retrieve = file_get_contents( $file );
if ( $retrieve === true ) {
    echo();
}
```

Due to the nature of PHP, it has to wait until the file_get_contents finishes, so it is it's own timer.

Bye

Answer (score 1):

Ajax: an acronym for **Asynchronous** JavaScript and XML

Of course getting a file will take time. The whole point of Ajax is that it is asynchronous, not blocking programming execution. As soon as the fetch is done, the function assosiated with success will be executed.